# Need Proof for below mentioned solution of CHAPD

Tags: algorithm

**Problem Link:** http://www.codechef.com/problems/CHAPD/
Explanation:

```
You are given two positive integers – A and B. 
You have to check whether A is divisible by all the prime divisors of B.
```

On of my friend told me this solution but I am unable to understand the logic behind this solution:

**Solution:**

```
import sys
t=int(sys.stdin.readline())
for _ in range(t):
    a,b=map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
    if (a**65)%b==0:
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
```

After observing this solution I was not able to understand why did author choose value **"65"** When I tried to test extreme value i.e. 10^18, 10^18 It gave Memory Error on PC.
I tested replacing value 65 with some random values that are
**64, 61, 45, 33, and 17** So I found that for value 17 one test case didn't passed and for other values code AC'ed for all values.
You may see the submissions [here](http://www.codechef.com/status/CHAPD,rishabhprsd7).
I just want to know the Proof for this solution.
**Thank You!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution relies on input value limitation. `B < 10**18` => `B < 2**60`, so any prime divisor in factorization of `B` have power lower then 60. Then if `A` has all the prime divisors of `B`, `A**60` has to be divisible by `B`, and if `A**60` is divisable by `B`, then it has all it's prime divisors and so has `A`.